# Need to buy sfx for chariot race  !! Asap

Tags: sfx

Eeek!! Short notice requires me to purchase and edit chariot race sfx please pm me if you have private library source that I can purchase .. Thanks !!

Comment: Can you be more specific? (Which period, wider or closer, single or group....)

Comment: I'll actually take almost anything I can get because I believe that it would be so rare for someone to have useable content so being specific limits my options

Answer (score 1):

Try searching [Sound Ideas](http://www.sound-ideas.com:90/sfx/searchsfx2.html).

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it will help